# Creating a list or array of nodes in javafx With ID in scene builder

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, objectid

I was working on a project in javafx and scene builder. the project demands 64 squares I create a gridpane  that take them. However I need to deal with the rectangles separately so I must create Square objects in my javacontrooller. But is there a way for creating one list for all of them so then I can use thier names in the scene builder Fx id.

I have tried array but it didn't work as the scene builder doesn't take the arrays structure as valid id for the object.

Comment: It just sounds like a bad idea to do this in FXML (which doesn’t easily support arrays or lists, and doesn’t support looping constructs at all). Do this in Java code instead.

Comment: Inject the `GridPane` into the controller, then add the squares in code (in the `initialize` method).